# Error when run nested vm in google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm facing a problem when I start nested VM in virtual manager,
my connection gets disconnected and I can't access ssh command line.

I'm using tightvnc to access server GUI.

[image]

Comment: Can you let me know which processor your VM is using? You can get this information by clicking your desired VM machine and checking the *‘CPU platform’* part.

Comment: I'm using Haskel or letter version of cpu with 4 vCPU and 10GB Ram

Comment: Seems like the CPU is enough for this to work. However, you can also check [all restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances#restrictions) which might block you from achieving the task.

That said, if the restrictions are OK in your case; you can share the steps you have taken to configure the guest and host machines with OS their types.

Comment: Yes actually it was working fine, I have been using it for a week but now I don't know why it is raising error.

Comment: As I asked in my previous comment, can you share the guest and host OS (i.e. Google Cloud Platform VM OS and OS of your nested VM) and steps you have followed to do the nested VM configuration?